# TCP server differences in operating systems

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, tcpclient

I have developed a tcp-server with qt in windows. about 10-20 clients connected the server and there is a data transfer between server and clients. There is different threads for every connected clients. The server, sends a packet and wait reply to this data packet if the ACK receive then sends the next packet. There is a timeout if there is no reply. If client does not send the answer in 2 minutes, my server sends the same packet again.

There is no problem with that. (By the way my computer windows7 home premium) When i take my application to the other computer with windows7 ultimate, If there is a timeout, instead of sending the same data packet again it is not doing anything. The other difference between my computer and this computer is, this computer dont have installed qt. I run my application with required dll's.

What can cause this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work at all on the other computer ? if not this might an issue with the firewall configuration...

Comment: Why are you reimplementing TCP? It already does all that.

Comment: There could be a bug in your code that results in undefined or implementation defined behaviour - why not show the relevant code?  Separately, TCP has built in retransmission logic - the whole idea of manually triggering resends on the same TCP connection is of dubious value.

Comment: "There is different threads for every connected clients" - that's another bad idea, if I understand you as saying that there's one thread per client. That *does not* scale well.

Comment: I am not re-implement tcp. I use QTcpServer to handle those things. but i have this problem. @Yahia I dont think this is a firewall configuration because, the process begans, it continue but some reason in different states it stops, nothing is going on. I have a log but nothing in it.

Comment: yes there is one thread that working for every client but the thread is specific for every client. sorry about my english.

Comment: @thehilmisu If you are retransmitting when you don't receive an ACK, you are indeed reimplementing TCP. The correct application behaviour in that circumstance would be to drop the connection, at least unless all your transactions are idempotent.

Comment: Are you testing to see if there are errors in your code? If not you might try checking for them and printing a message. Have you checked that your firewall/router is not blocking your connection?

Answer (score 1):

As a first thing is to keep nomenclature in order:

- IP sends *packets*
- TCP sends *segments*
- a socket sends a *data-stream*. (Concept different than *std::stream*)

IP is implemented as a device driver, TCP is implemented as a driver playing on top of it, soket is a library linked to an application (may be static or dynamic) and all QT stuff is a library that uses sockets to send data around.

The role of breaking a stream-flow into segments belongs to the socket library, the role to break a segment into packets, enumerate them, check if something is missing and ask for retrasmission belongs to TCP.

Your code should NOT take care of all of them: it just have to send and receive data, and manage the error condition that the underlying socket may report in case of persistent and unrecoverable TCP failure.

It's not your code role to define netwok timeouts (there are [well established and defined standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) out there that date 30+ years about it: doing other thing yourself just makes network manager life a mess, and adds no value to your application)

Your problem is most likely a conflict between your timing and "transmission control" and the underlying TCP negotiated timing (that depends -also- on avaliale buffer size in the drivers of both sides, and may vary not only depending on the OSs but also on what the Os are actually doing time over time) that makes the two control system to retrofit in an unstable way.

Comment: I understand thank you, but let me explain my problem with an image
http://s9.postimage.org/xrvcr8q9r/Untitled.png

Comment: But if the problem isn't transmission loss but the device not understanding the data I don't see the value of retransmission, then it's something wrong with what you're sending.

Comment: Sockets is not a library. The Sockets API consists mostly of system calls. It is not a library. It is all in the kernel.

Comment: @EJP: Unless you have a way to statically link your app into "the kernel" , the "kernel API" are sitting in a library you have to link, so that your language can have suitable function prototype and proxy to call to dispatch the call into the kernel.  Also, the socket library in sin WINSOCK32.DLL, that's different from KERNEL32.DLL. So, again, these both are library an "kernel" is no more clear what it should be ...